# How to find the sum of values of map whose key contains the given prefix?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a method with the following signature:

```
int sum(Map<String, Integer> map, String target) { }
```

I am trying to find the sum of values of the entries who key has the prefix as the given `target` string. I want to do this using streams. This is what I've done:

```
return map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter((k, v) -> k.startsWith(target))
    .map((k, v) -> v)
    .sum();
```

Compiler gives the following error:

> error: incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "sum of values of the entries who key match with the given "target" string". inside a map there can be only one key that matches a target string by definition.

Comment: thank you , i wanted to say prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map's `entrySet` returns a `Set<Map.Entry<K, V>>`.

Use Entry's `getKey` and `getValue` to access the key and value and use `mapToInt` and `sum`.

```
map.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().startsWith(target))
        .mapToInt(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .sum();
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `entrySet()` is a collection of `Entry<>`, there is no separate `k` and `v`. You should try something like this:

```
return map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter((entry) -> entry.getKey().equals(target))
    .mapToInt((entry) -> entry.getValue())
    .sum();
```

Or for your edited version with `startsWith`:

```
return map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter((entry) -> entry.getKey().startsWith(target))
    .mapToInt((entry) -> entry.getValue())
    .sum();
```

Comment: the overall approach might be sane, but there is a difference in `equals` and `startsWith`, and `sum` can be invoked upon mapping to Integer, Long, etc. for their specific implementations have that API.

Comment: @Naman OP changed the question after I posted my answer, initially in the question there was `equals`. Updated my answer and corrected the summing part.

Answer (score 1):

`map.entrySet().stream()` gives you a stream of `Map.Entry<K, V>` elements.

You should use `e -> e.getKey().startsWith(target)` to get the entries who's key has the prefix as the value `"target"`

`Map.Entry::getValue` gives you the values of the filtered entries so you can sum the values.

Try this:

```java
return map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getKey().startsWith(target))
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Map.Entry` is a single object that cannot be accessed by `(k, v) -> ...`. You can get that entry's key and value using its corresponding methods `getKey()` and `getValue()` or use a method reference and collect the sum of the values:

```
int sum(Map<String, Integer> map, String target) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getKey().startsWith(target))
            // use a lamda expression and call the method
            .collect(Collectors.summingInt(e -> e.getValue()));
}
```

or with a method reference

```
int sum(Map<String, Integer> map, String target) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getKey().startsWith(target))
            // use method reference
            .collect(Collectors.summingInt(Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```